# How is this proof is enough but the other one not?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my math book there are two questions asking if any vector in $\mathbb R^3$ has can only be written one way as the sum of an element of $U_1$ and an element of $U_2$.

In both examples $a,b,c∈\mathbb R$.

**In the First Question:** we have two spaces:  $$U_1 = \{(a,b,c)| a+b+c=0\} \\ U_2 = \{(a,b,c) \mid a=c \}$$

**In the SECOND Question:** we have two spaces:  $$U_1 = \{(a,0,0)\},\\  U_2 = \{(0,b,c)\}$$

The proof for the SECOND they says
lets say we have two ways to same vector so:
$$(a,0,0)+(0,b,c) = (d,0,0)+(0,e,f)$$
but we get
$$(a,b,c)=(d,e,f)$$
so must be only way for each vector on  $R^3$ from $U_1$ and $U_2$

But for the first question they showed two that $(0,0,0)$ vector have two ways, but lets say I do not succeed to find two ways for one vector (in the first question), if i will do the same way of proof in
FIRST Question if assume:
$$(0,a-c,c-a)+(a,b+c-a,a) = (0,d-f,f-d)+(d,e+f-d,d)$$
i will also get
$$
(a,b,c)=(d,e,f)
$$
So why here the proof is not enough, I mean how can I know I am wrong here? I don't see any difference between these two approaches.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Why are you assuming that the first coordinate is $0$ in your example?

Comment: If you want to mimic the proof in the second case, you should start with $(a,-(a+b), b)+(c,d,c)=(e,-(e+f),f)+(g,h,g)$ and try to show that this forces $(a,b,c,d)=(e,f,g,h)$, though you will not succeed.

Comment: U1 and U2 are sub spaces of R3, they want to show in both example that  U1+U2=R3 in Direct sum. so on the first quistion its not Direct sum because $0$ have two ways of U1+U2.

Comment: (a,b,c)∈$R^3$ so (a,b,c)=(0,a-c,c-a)+(a,b+c-a,a) | (0,a-c,c-a) ∈$U_1$,  (a,b+c-a,a) ∈$U_2$. in your example (a,−(a+b),b)+(c,d,c) ≠ (a,b,c) right?

Comment: Not every element in $U_1$ has first coordinate zero.

Comment: Please take a look at the [formatting faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  You can get along much more easily without littering html linebreaks everywhere.

Comment: @lulu i think That's the point I missed, that the coordinate doesn't have to be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one does not express vectors as $(0,a-c,c-a)+(a,b+c-a,a)$, it expresses them as
$(a,-a-c,-a-b)+(d,e,d)$.

If $(a,-a-c,-a-b)+(d,e,d)=(a',-a'-c',-a'-b')+(d',e',d')$
all you have learned is that

$(a+d,-a-c+e,-a-b+d)=(a'+d',-a'-c'+e',-a'-b'+d')$

But to make things simpler, let's just focus on finding $(a,-a-c,-a-b)+(d,e,d)=(0,0,0)$ with something other than all zeros.

In particular, you could look for something within $U_1\cap U_2$, for example $(1,-2,1)$ and then just negate it:

$(1,-2,1)+(-1,2,-1)=(0,0,0)+(0,0,0)$ are two distinct ways to express that vector with elements from $U_1$ and $U_2$.

Comment: I missed the point that the first coordinate of vector in $U_1$ does not have to be $0$.
that why I got stuck on this. thank you for your answer, tips and the post edit.